# Take final position after a force applied to a GameObject

Tags: unity-game-engine

I apply a force to a gameobject and it goes as expected. I want to take the final position of this gameobject when its velocity become zero. I use an algorithm like that

```
     void Shoot ()
 {
 ...
    if(Mouse button clicked)
     {
     gameobject.rigidbody.AddForce;
     shoot = true;
     }
 }

 void Update ()
 {
    Shoot();
    if(gameobject.rigidbody.velocity.magnitude==0 && shoot==true)
    {
     finalPosition==gameobject.transform.position;
     shoot = false;
    }
 }
```

However, for the very first instant frame I just shoot(Force is applied but velocity isnt changing instantly), velocity == 0 and shoot become true. That is why I take start position instead of final position.However, I need to take the position of GameObject after it goes and become zero velocity Can you please show me a way?

Answer (score 0):

Make shoot an int instead of a bool and set it to 0. When you shoot set it to 1 and then detect when it is greater that 0 in the update where you detect if it is true. When magnitude is 0 and shoot is 1, make shoot 2, then when magnitude is 0 and shoot is 2, record the position and set shoot to 0. NOTE: You may need to move this into the FixedUpdate method so that it only happens at the same rate as the physics calculations. Example below:

```
private void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
         //add you force
         shoot = 1;
    }
}

private void FixedUpdate()
{
    Shoot();
    if(shoot > 0 && gameobject.rigidbody.velocity.magnitude==0)
    {
        if (shoot == 1)
        {
            shoot = 2;
        }
        else
        {
            finalPosition==gameobject.transform.position;
            shoot = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is shrewd! Thanks bro. I want to ask you one more thing. Your solution is okay when velocity is not equal zero in the next frame. What about velocity becomes different from zero in 5-10 frames later instead of next frame?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean? Putting the code in fixed update means that the checks shouldn't happen until after the physics calculations have taken place, at which point the magnitude shouldn't be zero.

Comment: Think about that, I want to do exact same thing. However, instead of velocity.magnitude==0 I want to check as it is velocity.magnitude<=0.5. So  finalPosition==gameobject.transform.position will be activated in both start of movement and finish of movement. However, I want finalPosition==gameobject.transform.position is activated in only end of movement.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to code below you can notify magnitude between (0,0.5]

```
 void Shoot (){
    ...
    if(Mouse button clicked){
      gameobject.rigidbody.AddForce;
    }
 }

 void Update (){
    // First check shoot paramater for more performance
    if(shoot == false && ((gameobject.rigidbody.velocity.magnitude>0)
                      &&(gameobject.rigidbody.velocity.magnitude<=0.5))){ 
       Shoot();  //object start moving so do some job.
       shoot = true;  // the object is moving
       // now you can know your object has movement 
       // and also know  <=0.5 as you wish in comment.
    }else if(gameobject.rigidbody.velocity.magnitude==0 && shoot==true){
       finalPosition==gameobject.transform.position;
       shoot = false;
    }
 }
```

I think below is more good solution.

Firstly create enum in your class or seperate class to more proper and readable code.

```
public enum MovementState {
   Initial = 0,
   FirstMove = 1,
   Moving = 2,
   Stop = 3
}
```

And in your class you can add below.

```
public MovementState objectState = MovementState.Initial; //you can see this and changes in editor

 void Shoot (){
    ...
    if(Mouse button clicked){
      objectState = MovementState.Initial;
      gameobject.rigidbody.AddForce;
    }
 }

 void Update (){
    // First check shoot paramater for more performance
    if(objectState == MovementState.Initial && ((gameobject.rigidbody.velocity.magnitude>0)
                      &&(gameobject.rigidbody.velocity.magnitude<=0.5))){ 
       Shoot();  //object start moving so do some job.
       objectState = MovementState.FirstMove;
       // now you can know your object has movement 
       // and also know  <=0.5 as you wish in comment.
    }else if(objectState==MovementState.Moving && gameobject.rigidbody.velocity.magnitude==0){
       finalPosition==gameobject.transform.position;
       objectState = MovementState.Stop;
    }else if(objectState==MovementState.FirstMove){
       objectState = MovementState.Moving;
    }
 }
```

Maybe some syntax errors in code. I don't check it.